# struts 2.5 and struts jquery 4.0.1 grid loading

Tags: jquery, struts2, struts2-jquery, struts2-jquery-grid, jquery-2.0

To load a grid after submitting a form successfully, we used below submit tag.

```
<sj:submit id="submitForm"  onSuccessTopics="gridLoader" ...
```

and

```
$.subscribe("gridLoader", function(event, data) {       
    var recviedRequest =  event.originalEvent.request.responseJSON;
```

However in struts 2.5 and struts jquery 4.0.1, I get the

```
TypeError: event.originalEvent.request is undefined
```

Well I try to invest the `event` object to find if a new object is defined, but I could not find any thing. As struts jquery plugin uses jquery 2 I wonder if this is some thing with jquery 2.

Any comments!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be `onCompleteTopics` which is fired when Ajax request is completed.

There should be `event.originalEvent.request.responseText`.

The docs are updated to reflect versions you have mentioned. See [Form Submit with Events](https://github.com/struts-community-plugins/struts2-jquery/blob/release/4.0.1/struts2-jquery-showcase/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/content/form-event.jsp).

Comment: Thanks! I used your recommendation. Also may be a bug which will be fixed. https://github.com/struts-community-plugins/struts2-jquery/issues/45